# How can I change (and transition) DIV heights using D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

When I change the height of two DIVs directly using `set_direct()` and `reset_direct()`, all is well.

But when I attempt to do the same using D3 (and to add a transition) through `set_via_d3()` and `reset_via_d3()`, the DIV heights remain unchanged. Why?

[transition DIV height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkszL.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <style>
        div { width: 300px; }
        div#outerdiv  { height: 500px; background-color: #fdf; }
        div#topdiv    { height: 400px; background-color: #dff; }
        div#bottomdiv { height: 0px;   background-color: #ffd; display: 'none' }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerdiv">
        <div id="topdiv">
            <button onclick=set_via_d3();>Set</button>
            <button onclick=reset_via_d3();>Reset</button>
        </div>

        <div id="bottomdiv">
            <span>Bottom</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function set_direct() {
            document.getElementById('topdiv').style.height = '100px';
            document.getElementById('bottomdiv').style.height = '300px';
            document.getElementById('bottomdiv').style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
        function set_via_d3() {
            d3.select('topdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .attr('height', '100px');
            d3.select('bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .attr('height', '300px').attr('display', 'inline-block');
        } 
        function reset_direct() {
            document.getElementById('topdiv').style.height = '390px';
            document.getElementById('bottomdiv').style.height = '10px';
            document.getElementById('bottomdiv').style.display = 'none';
        }
        function reset_via_d3() {
            d3.select('topdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .attr('height', '390px');
            d3.select('bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .attr('height', '10px').attr('display', 'none');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you aren't selecting your divs:

`d3.select('topdiv')` should be `d3.select('#topdiv')`

Secondly, in the hierarchy of styling, `selection.style` will override `selection.attr`. The former sets the css, the latter sets the tag attributes (which are secondary to the css). Since you've defined heights in css, you need to use an approach like : `selection.style("height",height);`

I quickly put together a demo using your code below with those two changes:

```js
        function set_via_d3() {
            d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '100px');
            d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '300px').attr('display', 'inline-block');
        } 
        function reset_via_d3() {
            d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '390px');
            d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '10px').attr('display', 'none');
        }
```

```css
        div { width: 300px; }
        div#outerdiv  { height: 500px; background-color: #fdf; }
        div#topdiv    { height: 400px; background-color: #dff; }
        div#bottomdiv { height: 0px;   background-color: #ffd; display: 'none' }
```

```html
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  
      <div id="outerdiv">
        <div id="topdiv">
            <button onclick=set_via_d3();>Set</button>
            <button onclick=reset_via_d3();>Reset</button>
        </div>

        <div id="bottomdiv">
            <span>Bottom</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You fixed my problem (thanks!), but not my understanding. What _is_ the difference between style and attributes? For instance, style is in CSS; where/how do attributes normally go or get set? "Normally" as in "if we were not using D3.js".

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the attribute could be set in plain html with: `<div height="400">`, while the style could be set in plain html with `<div style="height: 400px">`.